# How to create or customize registration authentication in two step using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm just new to Laravel. What I want is to enhance my registration authentication in laravel having an environment of vagrant homestead.For example on the first page of the form the user will provide his name and email and there will be a button of "Next" which will lead to a second form. From the second form, there will be a password field to fill in before clicking the "Register" button.

I'm having some troubles to do that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this article:

https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/how-to-make-user-login-and-registration-laravel-5-1/

Comment: @Peter That article mostly focuses on login, not in registration.

Comment: Ah i supposed you need authentication solution also :)

Comment: Here some nice info about registration: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/registration-and-login-system?page=1

Comment: Yeah but I want to focus on registration specially on that two step page process. Login form for me is fine. Only the registration I want to enhance.

Comment: You could do this with some CSS and jQuery? Create two divs, first one holding your `name` and `email` fields and the second holding the `password`. When they click `next` use jQuery to hide the first div and show the second. Then when they submit it, just send it all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Define 2 functions in your controller for each step, and each page will post to its respective function

```
public function step1(Request $request)
{
    ... //whatever you do before

    session(['name' => $request->name]);
    session(['email' => $request->email]);
    return redirect()->to('step2');
}
```

Your second page could post to a function like this

```
public function step2(Request $request)
{
    ...//whatever you do 
    $name = session('name');
    $email = session('email');

    $password = $request->password;

    //Do registration

    /**
    * Removed saved items from session
    * Important to remove after registration, just in case the user refreshes the page before registration is over
    */
    $request->session()->forget('name');
    $request->session()->forget('email');

    //Finish with whatever you (email, confirmation, etc.)
}
```

Comment: Do I need to change something in the Routes?

Comment: This is my current routes:

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Comment: I see you are using Auth::routes(); This if for default authentication provided by laravel. You are trying to customize your registration, therefore you cannot use default configuration. Just make your own routes for that and add a controller. Both routes should be post. You could follow the links provided to you by other users to see how to do registration. I just show how to do registration in 2 steps.